# Importing FxCop custom rule for C# in Sonarqube 5.4

Tags: c#, sonarqube, fxcop

I wrote a FxCop rule for a little project in C#. I assume that the rule is correct, because if I run it by FxCopCmd on the project, I found the error.
I'm trying to import it in SonarQube 5.4 (C# plugin v5.1 I have not setted anything in there), but probably I'm wrong. In creating custom rule in SQ I refer to the CheckId of my rule that I put in Rules folder of FxCop.
To execute analysis I use:

```
1)MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe /k ... /n ... /v...
2)C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
3)MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

In point 2 in the writelog I can see that (between the others) the rule is executed and the error is found.
After point 3 I expect to see it in the analysis in SQ web interface, but I found all the others but not my custom rule.
Anyone help?

Comment: Did you enable the custom rule in the Quality Profile used by the project ?

Comment: yes, I think that probably something is wrong in the form to create the rule in SQ. I act as the only field to fill mandatory correct is the CheckId. The other field I filled with information of description, names freely

Comment: There is anyone else that can me give some help?